# Change tkinter menu radiobutton indicator

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, radio-button, indicator

Consider the menu below:

```
menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu.add_radiobutton(label='A', variable=flavour_value, value='a')
menu.add_radiobutton(label='B', variable=flavour_value, value='b')
```

When radiobutton is selected, it shows V (checked) indicator from the left of a label.
Is there a possibility to replace the V indicator with a circular one, like in regular tk.Radiobutton?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide any indicators you want, by setting the `image` and `selectimage` options to the image of your choice. The `image` is for an unselected button, and `selectimage` is for a selected button.

Comment: What is the area that image/selectimage cover? Isn't it going to replace all of the background of a radiobutton widget?

Comment: @Andrey: I recommend you try it and see.

Comment: Setting `image` and `selectimage` does not replace the default *tick* indicator (checked in Windows platform).  However using `indicatoron=0` can hide the *tick* indicator (and still not replaced by the provided images). Also `compound` option should be set in order to show both the image and the text together.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Tkinter is not able to replace the 'check' indicator. The only way is to hide it with *indicatoron=False*, as was correctly mentioned by @acw1668.

Adding an image (image=...) will place it in a wrong position. The x0 (aka left) of an image will be just where the text usually begins.

Below is a small working example:

```
img = Image.open('wave.png')
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

menu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu.add_radiobutton(label='A', variable=flavour_value, value='a', image=tkimg, compound='left', indicatoron=False)
menu.add_radiobutton(label='B', variable=flavour_value, value='b')
setattr(menu, 'img_a', tkimg)
```

The last line is needed to protect tkimg from garbage collection.

The result:
[image]